# PERL decode("UTF-8") - ошибка "Wide character"

Tags: perl, utf-8, decode

Apache 2.4.41 + Activestate Perl 5.28.1 64 bit;

Есть вот такой простенький код:

```
my $sql = "INSERT INTO theTable (title) VALUES (N'Заголовок')";
open(LOG, ">>log.txt");
print(LOG $sql . "\n");
close(LOG);
$sql = decode("UTF-8", $sql)
$dbh->do($sql);
```

Он работает, как надо. В текстовый файл записывается русский текст, в таблицу на MS SQL server записывается русский текст.

Ещё есть проект, не мой, который получает со страницы в бровзере данные, которые пользователь вводит в поля на форме, читает из текстового файла шаблон SQL запроса, подставляет туда введённые пользователем значения и выполняет запрос. В случае ввода русского текста в таблицу сохраняются нечитаемые знаки, вроде "Ð—Ð°Ð³Ð¾Ð»Ð¾Ð²Ð¾Ðº"
Я нашел в коде этого проекта место, которое сводится к вышенаписанному коду, только там не было ни записи в текстовый файл, ни decode(), и я их добавил.
В тестовый файл записался читаемый русский текст. А вот вызов decode() выдал ошибку "Wide character at C:/Perl64/site/lib/Encode.pm line 228". Подскажите, пожалуйста, что это такое и как мне с этим бороться?

Comment: возможно проблема в русском языке

Answer (score 0):

Если decode так ругается, значит Вы пытаетесь декодить то, что содержит символы с кодом больше 255. В 99% случаев - Вы пытаетесь декодить текст, который уже был декодирован.

Если база отображает данные так, как Вы показываете, значит она хочет их в latin/ascii кодировке.

Фикс - смотрите в строку подключения к базе или саму настройку таблиц. Там должно быть указано UTF-8 в качестве кодировки. Или смотрите на кодировку таблиц базы и кодируйте правильно.